# Merging a Dataframe with an empty Dataframe having a column header in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframes together; one which is an empty dataframe having a column header and the other one is a dataframe of size 18 x 600.

What I tried:

```
userQuestionVector1 = pd.read_csv("embedding1_3.csv")
userQuestionVector2 = pd.read_csv("embedding2_3.csv")
userQuestionVector = pd.concat([userQuestionVector1,userQuestionVector2],axis=1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[vector])
df_userQuestionVector = new_df.append(userQuestionVector)
print(df_userQuestionVector)
```

Over here, `vector` is a list of 600 strings.

```
['word2vec_q1_1', 'word2vec_q1_2', 'word2vec_q1_3', ..., 'word2vec_q1_300', 'word2vec_q2_1', ..., 'word2vec_q2_300']
```

Dimension of `new_df` is 0 x 600.

Dimension of `userQuestionVector1` and `userQuestionVector2` are 18 x 300.

Dimension of `userQuestionVector` is 18 x 600.

The output `df_userQuestionVector` is 18 x 1200 in dimension i.e., it is merging the two dataframes side by side leaving second half with NaN values.

```
  value1_1 value1_2 value1_3 ... value1_300 string1 string2 string3 ... string300
0 value2_1 value2_2 value2_3 ... value2_300  NaN     NaN     NaN   ...     NaN
1 value3_1 value3_2 value3_3 ... value3_300  NaN     NaN     NaN   ...     NaN
2 value4_1 value4_2 value4_3 ... value4_300  NaN     NaN     NaN   ...     NaN
.   .       .       .            .       .       .            .
.   .       .       .            .       .       .            .
```

The expected output should be 18 X 600 in dimension i.e., `df_userQuestionVector` should merge  below `new_df`.

```
   string1  string2  string3  ... string300
0  value1_1 value1_2 value1_3 ... value1_300
1  value2_1 value2_2 value2_3 ... value2_300
2  value3_1 value3_2 value3_3 ... value3_300
.   .       .       .            .       .    
.   .       .       .            .       .
```

I also tried:

```
frames=[new_df, userQuestionVector]
df_userQuestionVector = pd.concat(frames,axis=0)
```

But this gives me same result.

How should I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What's in `vector`? Why not just using append with the 2 dataframes?

Comment: @gionni vector is a list of 600 strings. Look at my updated question.

Comment: @gionni Which two dataframes you are mentioning?

Comment: Ignore it, sorry,  I was misinterpreting the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading the csv set the header to None and Instead of creating a `new_df` dataframe set the `userQuestionVector` dataframe columns to `vector` i.e change the code to

```
userQuestionVector1 = pd.read_csv("embedding1_3.csv", header= None)
userQuestionVector2 = pd.read_csv("embedding2_3.csv", header = None)
userQuestionVector = pd.concat([userQuestionVector1,userQuestionVector2],axis=1)
userQuestionVector.columns = vector
```

Hope this helps.